# How to removethe HTTPCache When user logs out when using MVP/Dagger and Repository Pattern

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm using OKHTTP and Retrofit to handle network calls, I'm not sure how can I clear the cache when user logs out,I'm using MVP/Repository pattern and dagger on my Project

This is the sample project I'm referring 
https://github.com/LadwaAditya/DaggerRetrofitOkhttp-Tutorial

```
OkHttpClient tempClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)// connect timeout
                    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)// socket timeout
                    .followRedirects(false)
                    .cache(provideHttpCache())
                    .addNetworkInterceptor(new ResponseCacheInterceptor())
                    .addInterceptor(new AddHeaderAndCookieInterceptor())
                    .build();

  private  Cache provideHttpCache() {
        Cache cache = new Cache(new File(Application.getAppInstance().getCacheDir(), CACHE_DIR_NAME), CACHE_SIZE);
        return cache;
    }
```

OKHTTP has a Cache.evict method but I'm not sure how expose this method

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried referencing your [Cache](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Cache.html) from your `OkHttpClient` on logout and calling `tempClient.cache().delete()`?  Both `delete()` and `evictAll()` appear to be public from the documentation.